# I graduated in the top or as a top

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases

what is the right way to say

> I graduated in the top 10 percent of my class with a cum laude honor **or**

> I graduated as a top 10 percent of my class with a cum laude honor

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that *as* could be appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

You are part of the overall percentage of graduates, more specifically the top 10%. As the graduates are seen as a collection of people, that you are within, it would be correct to refer to this as 'in' the top 10 percent.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'as' in the latter statement seems to suggest that the top 10 percent of your class is something very distinct from the rest of your class. Consider the following statements-

> I graduated as a biologist.
>
> I graduated as a physicist.

In general, I do not think that being in the top 10 percent of a class deserves this kind of distinction.

However, the former statement appears to imply that you are in a group of students (specifically the top 10 percent) which is what I think you want to convey.

**TL;DR:**

> I graduated in the top 10 percent of my class with a cum laude honor

is more appropriate.